# What are the points about representation of groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, soft-question, finite-groups

For a fixed (let say finite-, or Lie-, to respect the historical motivations) group, why does the study of all its linear representations over a fixed field, leads to some knowledge about its structure that wouldn't be posible to reach without this tool ? What are the fundamental key points to understand here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why we need to study representations of matrix groups?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153740/why-we-need-to-study-representations-of-matrix-groups)

Comment: From Herstein's Carus Monograph on Noncommutative Rings, at the head of the section on applying representation theory to obtain results about groups:  "It is difficult to see or explain why this machinery when turned loose on a group works so effectively, but work indeed it  does."

Comment: The purported duplicate is somewhat focussed to groups that are given as automorphism groups. Even if in a sense technically speaking it's the same (since every group is automorphism group of some structure), in practice, and especially for such a subjective question, it's another point of view. However, I voted for migration to MathSE.

Comment: @Steven Landsburg : Oh, maybe this is why I didn't manage to understand the deep reasons of why it works so well...I thought it was because of a lack of knowledge from my part..